# input button not responsive (overflowing container)

Tags: html, css

Before, I used a home-made submit call so I could have forms without `<form>` and `<input>` buttons. A button could for example look like this:

```
<div class="ui big green button">This is a long button that should not go off screen</div>
```

Now, though, I've switched to a different front-end library so I have to do this:

```
<input type="submit" class="ui big green button" value="This is a long button that should not go off screen" />
```

This, however, comes with the caveat that my `input` button isn't responsive to the window size, i.e. it doesn't grow thicker when the window is small, instead just disappears off screen.

I think this is because some strange styling is added automatically to `input` that I can't reach or change:

```
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    color: buttontext;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background-color: buttonface;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px 6px 3px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: buttonface;
}
```

There are way more than this and I don't know exactly what makes my button behave this way, so I don't know what to override (if I can).

Here's my code so you can see this in action:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/components/button.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="submit" class="ui big green button" value="This is a long button that should not go off screen" />

<div style="margin-top: 20px;" />

<div class="ui big green button">This is a long button that should not go off screen</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vLaf94t1/

What can I do to fix this simply?

Comment: Instead of `<div class="... button ...">` you can use `<button type="submit" class="ui big green button">` which gives you all the same flexibility of the div (full html markup within the button), instead of the restrictions of an `<input...>` [See it added to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/vLaf94t1/2/). Then you don't even need your own additional CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your button element:

```
white-space: normal;
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vLaf94t1/1/)

---

Buried deep in the user agent stylesheet is:

```
white-space: pre;
```

[image]

> [**16.6 White space: the `white-space`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#white-space-prop)
>
> This property declares how white space inside the element is handled.
>   Values have the following meanings:
>
> `normal`
>
> This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space,
>   and break lines as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> `pre`
>
> This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white
>   space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.

Comment: To those that may be wondering, this CSS property is fully supported by almost all browsers. Also IE8+ supports it according to W3C: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score -2):

just add to your stylesheet:

```
display: block;
```

it takes care of that for you

Comment: Nope. The working button is `inline-block` by the way.